# Running Serverless template Webpack build standalone

Tags: node.js, webpack, serverless-framework

I started working with serverless and I would like to know why I am unable to run the Webpack build without going through the Serverless framework

- webpack --version 4.32.0
- npm --version 6.9.0
- serverless --version 1.43.0

`serverless create --template aws-nodejs-typescript`

From here, `serverless deploy` works (and any other command) but

> webpack

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry should be an instance of function
      -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.
    * configuration.entry should not be empty.
      -> Multiple entry bundles are created. The key is the chunk name. The value can be a string or an array.
    * configuration.entry should be a string.
      -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the webpack serverless uses is none standard webpack configuration. You can use `serverless package` instead of webpack directly.